# Managing UserContext in Django

Tags: django

Im using the following statement to set Language Option in my projects which works as expected.

```
request.session['django_language'] = "de"
```

This is fine with in View, but when the control goes to other files to connect to DB or external services how can I access it. I dont want to pass the request object through out all the application.

If something like UserContext/RequestContext where every request has to go-through it (Middleware) so that I can set it there and access it without help if request object.

Comment: I'm guessing that you have some form of User/Session object that you already pass around application and you should set the language there. As for middleware it's super easy to write one yourself, but it seems as you wouldnt benefit from it unless you have an object that you have access to everywhere already.

Answer (score 0):

I understand from the headline that you want to store the language per user.
It might be best to [extend the user model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) and add a model field for `preferred_language`.